# Autowiring in implementation classes of an interface in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm having a Spring boot application in which based on a variable, I need to call corresponding implementation classes of an interface. This is what I have right now:

```
public interface Parent{
    public void call();
}

public class ABC implements Parent{
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Called ABC");
    }
}

public class XYZ implements Parent{
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Called XYZ");
    }
}

@Service("caller")
public class Caller{
    @Autowired
    protected OrderInfoRepository orderInfoRepository; 

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    public Caller(){
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }

    public void callMethod(String param){
        Parent p = (Parent) context.getBean(param+"_Caller");
        p.call();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config{
    @Bean(name="ABC_Caller")
    public Parent getABC(){
        return new ABC();
    }

    @Bean(name="XYZ_Caller")
    public Parent getXYZ(){
        return new XYZ();
    }
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends Repository<MyDAO, Long> {
    // ....
}
```

Basically what I want to do is, based on the param passed to Caller.callMethod(), I want to add "_Caller" to the param, and call the corresponding implementation class. So, I'm defining a @Configuration class, where I define which implementation class to return. And then using the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, I get the corresponding bean. This works fine.

The problem I'm having is, when I try to Autowire anything in the implementation classes, I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. For instance, when I autowire in the implementation class ABC

```
public class ABC implements Parent{
    @Autowired
    MyRepo myRepo;

    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Called ABC");
    }
}
```

I get `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.persistence.repositories.MyRepo]` when I try to start the application. However, when I do the Autowiring in the Caller class instead, it works fine. I had asked a similar question a while back, but was not able to resolve it. Any ideas?

Comment: have you declared the MyRepo method as bean in any config file

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with the repo. I am able to Autowire it in Caller.class (I've updated the question).

Comment: Your Caller class, when it's instantiated, creates a completely new, separate application context, and gets the Parent beans from that separate application context, containing only 2 beans: XYZ and ABC. So, no, this context doesn't contain any repository.

Comment: Thanks. So how else can I get the application context?

Comment: @JBNizet any suggestions?